# Two Endogenous Variables and Two Instruments

Tags: econometrics

I have a model $Z = \alpha X + \beta Y + \gamma C + \epsilon$. I am interested in the relative effects of $X$ and $Y$ on $Z$. However, $X$ and $Y$ are endogenous. I have identified two instruments $X'$ and $Y'$ respectively. $C$ is an exogenous control variable (fixed effect).

How do I go about estimating the model with these two instruments for the two endogenous variables? Do I need to use 3SLS? I am fairly new to this field. Any resources that address this would be very helpful, thank you.

Comment: No need for 3sls, you can just run 2sls as you normally would.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you need anything like a 3SLS. Just run the first stage for the two endogenous variables separately:

$$\tilde{X}=\alpha_1+\beta_1X'+\beta_2Y'+\beta_3C+\epsilon$$
$$\tilde{Y}=\kappa_1+\gamma_1X'+\gamma_2Y'+\gamma_3C+\delta$$

Then run a regression of Z on the predicted value of $\tilde{X}$, $\tilde{Y}$ as and $C$. If the assumptions are all satisfied, this should give a consistent estimate of the coefficients.

I also found this thread online. It might be helpful.
https://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2012-08/msg01238.html

Comment: I have a related question; https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/525706/if-i-have-two-endogenous-variables-for-which-i-each-have-an-instrument-do-i-abs?noredirect=1#comment967613_525706 Would you have any idea?